# When compiling Less client-side, how to trigger a listener when "less has finished"?

Tags: less

Referring to: http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser

The compilation can sometimes take a while, how do you add a listener to be called when the compilation has finished on the page?

Comment: There's `less.pageLoadFinished` promise you can set. It's undocumented but should be pretty self evident to use... (e.g. `less.pageLoadFinished.then(... yourCallback ...);`)

Answer (score 0):

There's `less.pageLoadFinished` promise you can set. It's undocumented but should be pretty self evident to use... (e.g. `less.pageLoadFinished.then(...yourCallback ...);`)